# WPF RichTextBox remove first or last line

Tags: c#, wpf, line, richtextbox

I would like to remove my First line of the RichTextBox after x number of lines have exceeded.

Now I have this code which counts the lines:

```
Int32 getLineCount(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    Int32 result = -1;

    rtb.CaretPosition = rtb.Document.ContentStart;

    while (rtb.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(++result) != null)
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

However the code to actually remove the last line of the RichTextBox is hard to do. Anyone that can provide an example or link where I can find out how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First you can add text to the RichTextBox like so:

```
Paragraph p = box.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;
TextRange textrange = new TextRange(box.Document.ContentEnd, box.Document.ContentEnd);
textrange.Text = text;
```

Now you can remove the first or last line using this code:

```
box.Document.Blocks.Remove(box.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock); //First line
box.Document.Blocks.Remove(box.Document.Blocks.LastBlock); //Last line
```

Comment: My idea on how this code works. You will add a new FirstBlock as paragraph everytime you add. This way when you delete the FirstBlock it will delete the FirstBlock of all the FirstBlocks that are in there. Feel free to add additional info that can be handy. I'm not that good in WPF things.